# How to test consistency of two assertions without hacking

Tags: assumptions, expression-test

Suppose I have a set of assumptions `assum = x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals` and I want to test an assertion like

```
ineq = (-(x^2*y) + x^2*Sqrt[y*(-x^2 + y)])/(-(x^2*y) + Sqrt[-(x^2*y*(-x^2 + y))]) > 1
```

How do I do this functionally?

```
FullSimplify[assum && ineq];

Refine[assum && ineq];

Assuming[assum, Assumptions`AImpossibleIneqQ[ineq]];
```

All fail to give the correct answer (first two should give `False`, last one `True).  What to do???

---

The only *hack* I can think of, which is not functional, and which I wish to avoid is:

```
$Assumptions = assum && ineq;
```

and look for a `$Assumptoins::cas` error.  But I want to avoid this.  What is the function *Mathematica* is using to resolve a set of assumptions???

Comment: `Reduce[ineq, {x, y}]` gives `False` even without the assumptions... Am I missing something?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer  I definitely missed that thanks!  Please answer it so I can accept.  Please also point out that if I want to include additional assumptions, they have to be appended with `And`.

Comment: I'd rather you self-answer the post :) That way you know what to include, and maybe you have a nice example showing how it works as well.